# Redux how to access state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, reducers

I'm having trouble accessing the state in one of my components. I have a component where a user adds a name and a weight and then submits it. They are then redirected to the Home Page. What I want to happen is for the name that was inputed to be displayed on the Home Page. I can see the state updating, but I can't figure out how to access the state and have the name show on the Home Page. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my Home Page component:

```
const HomePage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const name  = useSelector(state => state.move.name);
    const displayMovementButtons = () => {
        if (name) {
            return (
                <Button 
                    className={classes.movementButtons}
                    onClick={() => history.push('/movement/:id')}
                >   
                    <div className={classes.movementName} >{name}</div>
                </Button>
            )
        }; 

        return <div className={classes.noMovementsMessage} >Click add button to begin</div>
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.homePageContent} >
            <Header title={"Home Page" }/>
            <div>{displayMovementButtons()}</div>
            <div className={classes.fabDiv}>
                <Fab 
                    className={classes.fab}
                    onClick={() => history.push(`/add`)}>  
                    <AddIcon />      
                </Fab>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.move.name,  
    }   
};

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
);

export default compose(withConnect)(HomePage);
```

Here is my reducer, where I think the problem is:

```
const initialState = []

const addMovementReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MOVEMENT: 
            return [ ...state, {name: action.name, weight: action.weight} ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default addMovementReducer;
```

Here is a screenshot showing the state (note: I added multiple names and weights, I would eventually like each 'name' to appear on the Home Page):
[image]

Comment: your "move" state is an array.. so when you are accessing it, you would have to use something like this: state.move[0].name

Answer (score 0):

Your `move` branch of state is an array. You can't access the name by `state.move.name`. Instead of this you can get an array of movements from redux store and render them with `Array.map()` method.

```
const MovementButtons = ({ movements }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                movements.map(({ name, weight }) => {
                    if (name) {
                        <Button
                            className={classes.movementButtons}
                            onClick={() => history.push('/movement/:id')}
                            key={name}
                        >
                            <div className={classes.movementName}>{name}</div>
                        </Button>
                    }

                    return (
                        <div className={classes.noMovementsMessage}>Click add button to begin</div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}

const HomePage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const movements  = useSelector(state => state.move);

    return (
        <div className={classes.homePageContent} >
            <Header title={"Home Page" }/>
            <MovementButtons movements={movements} />
            <div className={classes.fabDiv}>
                <Fab
                    className={classes.fab}
                    onClick={() => history.push(`/add`)}>
                    <AddIcon />
                </Fab>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.move.name,
    }
};

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
);
```